# Make fails attempting to install svn-1.0.2

Tags: svn, pecl, make

Trying to figure out whats going on with this error so we can successfully install `svn-1.0.2`

I am using the command, `echo -e "\n" |pecl install svn-1.0.2`

```
root@us-east-1d-tengu-queuerunner-prod-141-8.mhecloud.com[/logs/apache]> echo -e "\n" |pecl install svn-1.0.2
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/svn.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/svn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/geoip.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/geoip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
downloading svn-1.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download svn-1.0.2.tgz (25,226 bytes)
.........done: 25,226 bytes
4 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
Please provide the prefix of Subversion installation [autodetect] : Please provide the prefix of the APR installation used with Subversion [autodetect] : building in /var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2
running: /var/tmp/svn/configure --with-svn --with-svn-apr
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for svn support... yes, shared
checking for specifying the location of apr for svn... yes, shared
checking for svn includes... Found libsvn 1.7.4
checking for apr and apr-util... Found apr 1.4.6
libsvn includes: "-I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE"
libsvn ldflags: "-lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_fs-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -L/usr/lib64 -lapr-1"
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/include/subversion-1  -I/usr/include/apr-1  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/var/tmp/svn -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/main -I/var/tmp/svn -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/svn/svn.c -o svn.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/var/tmp/svn -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/main -I/var/tmp/svn -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/svn/svn.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/svn.o
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘init_svn_client’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:354: warning: ‘svn_client_get_simple_provider’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:151)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:357: warning: ‘svn_client_get_username_provider’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:198)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:360: warning: ‘svn_client_get_ssl_server_trust_prompt_provider’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:265)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:364: warning: ‘svn_client_get_ssl_server_trust_file_provider’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:214)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:367: warning: ‘svn_client_get_ssl_client_cert_file_provider’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:231)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:370: warning: ‘svn_client_get_ssl_client_cert_pw_file_provider’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:248)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_config_ensure’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:454: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_import’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:495: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:497: warning: ‘svn_client_import’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:1885)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_checkout’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:741: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:742: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:753: warning: ‘svn_client_checkout2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:1147)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_cat’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:825: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_ls’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:895: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:906: warning: ‘svn_client_ls2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:4936)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_log’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1112: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1128: warning: ‘svn_client_log3’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:2500)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_diff’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1283: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1284: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1286: warning: ‘svn_client_diff3’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:2839)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_cleanup’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1350: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_revert’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1391: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1393: warning: ‘svn_client_revert’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:3704)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_resolved’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1433: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1435: warning: ‘svn_client_resolved’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:3728)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_file_contents’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1650: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_file_length’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1692: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_node_prop’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1734: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_node_created_rev’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1779: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_dir_entries’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1824: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_check_path’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1869: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_repos_open’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1932: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:1934: warning: ‘svn_repos_open’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_repos.h:383)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_info’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2026: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2047: warning: ‘svn_client_info’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:5508)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_export’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2099: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2100: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2111: warning: ‘svn_client_export3’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:4750)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_switch’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2152: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2153: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2161: warning: ‘svn_client_switch’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:1440)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_copy’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2205: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2206: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2218: warning: ‘svn_client_copy2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:3941)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_blame’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2318: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2339: warning: ‘svn_client_blame2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:2670)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_delete’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2386: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2388: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2390: warning: ‘svn_client_delete2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:1735)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_mkdir’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2459: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2461: warning: ‘svn_client_mkdir2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:1630)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_move’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2528: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2529: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2531: warning: ‘svn_client_move3’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:4113)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_proplist’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2591: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2602: warning: ‘svn_client_proplist2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:4590)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2630: warning: ‘svn_path_local_style’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:82)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2630: warning: ‘svn_path_local_style’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:82)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_propget’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2673: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2684: warning: ‘svn_client_propget2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:4484)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2706: warning: ‘svn_path_local_style’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:82)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2706: warning: ‘svn_path_local_style’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:82)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_repos_create’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2750: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_repos_recover’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2795: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2797: warning: ‘svn_repos_recover2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_repos.h:614)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_repos_hotcopy’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2835: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2836: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_commit’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2916: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2925: warning: ‘svn_client_commit3’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:2018)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_lock’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:2985: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_unlock’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3036: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_add’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3087: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3089: warning: ‘svn_client_add2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:1535)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_status’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3193: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3198: warning: ‘svn_client_status2’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:2364)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_update’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3257: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3262: warning: ‘svn_client_update’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_client.h:1315)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_repos_fs_begin_txn_for_commit’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3330: warning: ‘svn_repos_fs_begin_txn_for_commit’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_repos.h:1920)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_make_file’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3437: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_make_dir’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3475: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_apply_text’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3516: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_copy’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3564: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3565: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_delete’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3604: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_is_file’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3681: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_is_dir’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3720: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_change_node_prop’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3760: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_contents_changed’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3811: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3812: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c: In function ‘zif_svn_fs_props_changed’:
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3859: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/var/tmp/svn/svn.c:3860: warning: ‘svn_path_canonicalize’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/subversion-1/svn_path.h:282)
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/main -I/var/tmp/svn -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o svn.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /var/tmp/pear-build-roota11OW6/svn-1.0.2/modules  svn.lo -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -lsvn_client-1 -lsvn_fs-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lsvn_subr-1 -lapr-1
/bin/grep: /usr/lib64/libneon.la: No such file or directory
/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib64/libneon.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib64/libneon.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make: *** [svn.la] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/lib64/libneon.la` is missing. You'll have to install whatever package for your OS provides it then try building again.

This might help

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138650/cant-find-lib-which-provides-libneon-so-25

Comment: accepted and plus one

Answer (score 0):

Try to install below:

`subversion`

`subversion-devel`

`neon-devel`

Taken from this link:
https://github.com/aholmes/php-svn/issues/2